# Open Extremely Large .xlsx, Change the Contents of One Small Sheet, and Save

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx, large-files

I am running into trouble trying to reformat a very small worksheet of a very, very large .xlsx file.  The files are too large for openpyxl to read without read_only=True.
My current strategy is to open the file with read_only=True, copy the the worksheet information I need to change into a temporary workbook for modification, then open a third workbook to write out the modified sheet and copy over the unmodified sheets.  However, when I try to use the below method, I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py",
> line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
> os.remove(path)  PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
> 'C:\Users\NAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\openpyxl.no3fot8y'

```
sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
rwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
twb = openpyxl.Workbook(sheetnames)
wwb = openpyxl.Workbook(sheetnames, write_only=True)

copyWorksheetIntoOtherWorkbook(rwb, sheetnames[0], wwb, sheetnames[0])

def copyWorksheetIntoOtherWorkbook(source_wb, sheetname, destination_wb, newsheetname):
    if sheetname not in destination_wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = destination_wb.create_sheet(newsheetname)
    else:
        sheet = destination_wb[newsheetname]
    for row in source_wb[sheetname].iter_rows():
        sheet.append(list(row))
```

My suspicion is that openpyxl uses the same filename(s) for the temporary files used for both read_only and write_only workbooks.  Is there a way to allow both to function simultaneously?
If this cannot be made to work, is there another way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Such a conflict shouldn't be happening because openpyxl is asking for new files each time. But your code as is will not run correctly so it could be something else.